# Random high idle wont decrease speed when driving sies when still

Tags: chevrolet, power, idle, trailblazer

2004 chevy trailblazer ls erratic idle speed, sluggish power when increasing speed, high power preventing speed to decrease bellow 35 when decreasing speed without breaking hard, last obd2 freeze frame :

```
load% 27.5
Etc°F 194
Shrt ft 1:  2.3
Lng ct 1: -4.7
MAP (inHg)  9.7
RPM   629 
VSS 0
Spark Adv. 13
IAT°F. 72 
TP%   19.2
```

- incomplete monitors: catalyst and secondary air
- N/a: heated catalyst, egr system, a;c refridge.

Please anybody have any ideas what could be the cause, for my to look into

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I might start with vacuum leaks; the wickedest stuff is often quite simple.